# What's the purpose of inheriting QAbstractTableModel, QAbstractListModel, etc. for ListView, GridView and TableView

Tags: qt, inheritance, qml, abstract-class

I could have a simple `QVector, QList,` etc. of `QObject` to present in `ListView`, `GridView` and `TableView` and add/edit/remove items in/from those `View`. To me using `QVector, QList,` etc. of `QObject*` is the easiest way to accomplish the ultimate goal. What's the real benefit of inheriting `QAbstractTableModel`, `QAbstractListModel`, etc.? In WPF we've `VirtualizingStackPanel` and some properties to boost performance in such type of `View`. Does inheriting those `Abstract..Model` serve the same purpose or either way (inheriting or using plain `QVector/QList`), performance will be same?

Comment: Please make substantial edits, so far you have made trivial edits. If you want to attract positive attention, show what you have advanced, for example, show 2 MRE where you see that both cases are equivalent and then the community can point out differences in that specific case.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I think the experienced `Qt community` should advance spontaneously and type `Yes/No` to save my/our time and give me/us straight forward answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc, no! For most of my problems I didn't even have to ask any question. I found many answers here on this site and in plenty of cases I've observed people asking a `single-line question` and experienced programmers posted tons of answer explaining the matter/issue with tons of examples, that's why I like stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Well, as I indicated it is a recommendation, if you want to take it, and if you want not. I will continue my way. :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc, ok, that's your preference and I've no problem with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantages of QAbstractItemModel and subclasses are mainly increased performance when handling larger lists, and increased flexibility by using proxy models:

1. Partial updates: A model can tell the view that single rows or ranges of rows were [inserted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted), [moved](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved), [removed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsRemoved) or [updated](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) which then the view can act upon in a smarter way than throwing away and rebuilding everything. The cost of inserting an item in the middle of 10k other items is cheap, for example.
2. Lower overhead: A large list of, say, 50k QObject*s would have a major overhead, both in cost for the objects themselves and in handling all the signal/slot connections for handling the property updates.
3. A model can act as an adapter to an already existing data structure, without the need to hold all the data in the model (although that can be tricky in practice, to guarantee correctness/consistency)
4. Lazy-loading: The model can load data on demand as the user is navigating the view, without having to have all data already available (see [fetchMore()/canFetchMore()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore)).
5. Flexibility through proxies: [QAbstractProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html) and subclasses (in particular, [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)) allow stacking of models to filter/sort/modify the data in the original model. With [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) sorting and filtering is usually much simpler to implement (and without changing the original data/model) than implementing it manually for a QList. Simple modifications like changing the returned data for a certain role can be implemented by subclassing [QIdentityProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html).
6. More complex data structures: QAbstractItemModel also allows for trees (tricky to implement though) and tables. These are more often used in "traditional" (QWidget-based) desktop UIs than in embedded/mobile touch UIs though.